# How to make multiple choices be the default in an argparse argument, but one or more chocies be optional?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to add an argument to my parser in which there are multiple choices that can be selected from a certain argument. However, by default, I want all three options to be run by default unless the user indicates that he or she wants to run only one or two of the possible options.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output_type",
        choices= ['count', 'proportion', 'percentage'],
        default= 'count', 'proportion', 'percentage')

    args= parser.parse_args()

    if args.output_type == ['count','proportion','percentage']:
        ###do stuff
    elif args.output_type == 'percentage' or args.output_type == 'count' or args.output_type == 'proportion':
        ###do stuff
    else:
        ###raise error
```

But it does not seem to work properly. It might be that my conditional tree is set up incorrectly, but I'm not sure. Can anybody advise me on how to organize this better?

Comment: When you say "it does not seem to be formatted properly", what do you mean? Does the code give you an error when you try to run it, or does it run but not behave how you want?

Comment: @bouteillebleu made a slight mix-up with the words. I have amended the error above. I meant to say that the code does not work.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Does it give you an error message? If so, adding the error message into the post will help people in solving this for you.

Comment: @bouteillebleu sadly, because I am on a different computer than where my code is stored, I don't have access to the particular error at this time. I can try to maybe recreate a simplified version on this computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your code as posted I get a SyntaxError

```
  File "stack44160281.py", line 10
    default= 'count', 'proportion', 'percentage')
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

`default= 'count'` is ok, but the next two strings don't fit the function's argument specs.

You probably intended it to be

```
default= ['count', 'proportion', 'percentage']
```

But now I get: `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`  You forgot the `args = parser.parse_args()` line.

And the indentation of the last lines is wrong.

After correcting all those things (any of which merits a `close` vote)(and adding a diagnostic `print(args)` line).

```
1436:~/mypy$ python stack44160281.py 
Namespace(output_type=['count', 'proportion', 'percentage'])
do default

1436:~/mypy$ python stack44160281.py -o count
Namespace(output_type='count')
do stuff
1437:~/mypy$ python stack44160281.py -o percentage
Namespace(output_type='percentage')
do stuff
1438:~/mypy$ python stack44160281.py -o wrong
usage: stack44160281.py [-h] [-o {count,proportion,percentage}]
stack44160281.py: error: argument -o/--output_type: invalid choice: 'wrong' (choose from 'count', 'proportion', 'percentage')
1438:~/mypy$ python stack44160281.py -h
usage: stack44160281.py [-h] [-o {count,proportion,percentage}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o {count,proportion,percentage}, --output_type {count,proportion,percentage}
```

The `elif` line could be condensed to:

```
elif args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:
```

The `default` could be replaced by almost any string, e.g.  `default='DEFAULT'` and `if args.output_type == 'DEFAULT'`  It could even be left as the default `None`, and tested with `if args.output_type is None:`.

You could have added another choice such as `'all'` and use that as the `default`.  That would let your user provide that value.

Note that the `choices` keeps us from getting to the `else` error line.

In fact the dispatching could be condensed to:

```
if args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:
    print('do stuff')
else:
    print('do default')
```

since the value is guaranteed to be one of the `choices` or the `default`.

Note this setup is not a multiple choice question.  Your user still has to provide just one of the choices, not several.  With a change in `nargs` or `action` we could change that.  And we also need to change the testing.

---

If `output_type` has an `nargs='+'` parameter, then `args.output_type` will be a list.  You could test for a specific list with:

```
if args.output_type == ['one', 'two']:
```

But what if the user gave you `['two', 'one']` instead.

Usually a list is tested with something like:

```
for value in args.output_type:
   if value in ['one', 'two']:
        <act>
   else if value in ['three']:
        <act>
   else:
        <act>
```

If you want to test for both values at once, you might use a `set`, so the order doesn't matter.

There's lots of ways of organizing the logic.  It depends on what the values mean to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, but could you tell me what I would need to do to `nargs` or `action` in order to accommodate more than one of the answers?

Comment: Have you tried `nargs='+'`?  `args.output_type` should then be a list with one or more strings.

Comment: I did try that, but it won't work. It either takes one choice, or all choices (which is the default when the program is run in the command line without the `-o` flag. I might have set my conditional tree of my dispatching incorrectly. Should I add extra parts to it, such as `elif args.output_type == ['percentage', 'count']: ...`, in order for it to accommodate two of the three choices?

Comment: Was the problem with the `argparse` output, or your condition tree?  WIth a lists of strings you'll have to change the testing.  A common way is to iterate on the list, and test each element.

Comment: I think the problem might be in my condition tree. Do you think I should set up a loop like `for output in args.output_type: ...`?

Comment: I changed my conditional tree so that the singular choices followed the format `elif args.output_type == ['count]'` while the double choices followed the format `elif args.output_type == ['count', 'percentage'] and ['percentage', 'count']`. the `else` branch then handled my default case, which was all three choices being run.

Comment: I'm not following the options that you are trying test for, but I added a few notes.

Answer (score 0):

When i try to run your code (from python 2.7 which i am using) it gives `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. So if you want to set all of the choices as default you could use `default` built-in function, just set `default = all`. Secondly `args` should be parsed before used which is `args = parser.parse_args()`

Edit: As @hpaulj said, `elif args.output_type == 'percentage' or args.output_type == 'count' or args.output_type == 'proportion':` could be simplified as `elif args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:`

I hope following can help:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output_type",
        choices = ['count', 'proportion', 'percentage'],
        default = all)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.output_type == all:
    print "all"
elif args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:
    print "one"
else:
    print "error"
```

Comment: thank you! also, just a quick additional question, because we set a default in the argument, that means we do not need to specify the argument in the command line when we run it, correct?

Comment: Yes if you want to run it with default, no need to specify.

Comment: `all` is a builtin function.

Comment: `elif args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:` is shorter.

Comment: @hpaulj although doing `elif args.output_type in ['percentage', 'count', 'proportion']:` is shorter, I'm afraid it does not carry out the functions I want. I have to build up three different dicts with the three options, and trying to specify which dicts to build in the previously described `elif` clause is not practical for my purposes.